# Im getting a getting Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type. How can I fix this table to the right format for sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

table in sqlite. I think its the tumbnails. Can someone let me know what to use for a jpg link

```
CREATE TABLE youtube_video (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    published_at TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    channel_id TEXT,
    thumbnails TEXT,
    channel_title TEXT,
    view_count INTEGER,
    like_count INTEGER,
    dislike_count INTEGER,
    favorite_count INTEGER,
    duration TEXT,
    video_id TEXT,
    transcript TEXT
);
```

code in pycharm to add data to sqlite table.  cursor.execute(insert_query, (

```
                            cursor.execute(insert_query, (
                                snippet['publishedAt'],
                                snippet['title'],
                                snippet['channelId'],
                                snippet['thumbnails'],
                                snippet['channelTitle'],
                                statistics.get('viewCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('likeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('dislikeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('favoriteCount', 0),
                                content_details['duration'],
                                video_id,
                                transcript,
                            ))
                            ))
```

Im getting a getting Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type. How can I fix this table to the right format for sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should sort it out:

```
cursor.execute(insert_query, (
                                str(snippet['publishedAt']),
                                str(snippet['title']),
                                str(snippet['channelId']),
                                str(snippet['thumbnails']),
                                str(snippet['channelTitle']),
                                statistics.get('viewCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('likeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('dislikeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('favoriteCount', 0),
                                content_details['duration'],
                                video_id,
                                transcript,
                            ))
                            ))
```